# for loop with list and sublist to foreach loop

Tags: r, loops, foreach

I tried to get this `for` loop into a `foreach` loop to finally run it in parallel. But I think I didn't get the concept of the `foreach` loop right. I tried around with simpler loops and always got stuck.

The simplified code of the original for loop:

```
varName <- rep("name",1000)
testlist <- list()
for(j in 1:1000){

testlist [[j]]              <- list()
testlist [[j]]$UsedAlgo     <- "Name"
testlist [[j]]$UsedPMethod  <- varName[j]
testlist [[j]]$datalists    <- list()
testlist [[j]]$datalists    <- lapply(Dataset[[j]]$data,     
                                function(x){#whateverfunction})
```

My foreach loop:

```
 library(foreach)
 library(doMC)
 registerDoMC(35)
 varName <- rep("name",1000)

 testlist <- foreach(j=1:1000) %dopar% {

 testlist[[j]] <- list()
 testlist[[j]]$UsedAlgo     <- "Name"
 testlist[[j]]$UsedPMethod  <- varName[j]
 testlist[[j]]$patterns     <- list()
 testlist[[j]]$patterns     <- lapply(Dataset[[j]]$data,                
                                      function(x){#whateverfunction})

 }
```

So it runs kind of fine. It outputs the lists which are returned by #whateverfunction. But completely ignores the other variable settings.

List returned is a list ranging from 1:1000 with the output of #whateverfunction. The function is compley and returns lots of lists and is written in C++. That's why I did not attach a completely running example. But I can figure one out if needed. But I think I just did a basic mistake and maybe I just googled the wrong tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `testlist[[j]]` with `temp` and adding an explicit return at end: `return(temp)`:

```
testlist <- foreach(j=1:1000) %dopar% {    
   temp <- list()
   temp$UsedAlgo     <- "Name"
   temp$UsedPMethod  <- varName[j]
   temp$patterns     <- lapply(Dataset[[j]]$data,                
                               function(x){ ... })
   return(temp)
}
```